# ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.None

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

ERROR:   Getting the following error while trying to sbt run a spark program trying to access cassandra written in scala 
    [enter link description here](https://github.com/koeninger/spark-cassandra-example/issues/2)

```
Ubuntu Command Line EXCEPTION:

18/06/03 17:35:13 **ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.None**$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
**18/06/03 17:35:14 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.None$**
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/06/03 17:35:14 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver, partition 2, NODE_LOCAL, 15215 bytes)
18/06/03 17:35:14 **ERROR** TaskResultGetter: Could not deserialize TaskEndReason: ClassNotFound with classloader sbt.classpath.ClasspathFilter@7edf86d3
18/06/03 17:35:14 INFO Executor: Running task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
18/06/03 17:35:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): UnknownReason
18/06/03 17:35:14 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
18/06/03 17:35:14 ERROR TaskResultGetter: Could not deserialize TaskEndReason: ClassNotFound with classloader sbt.classpath.ClasspathFilter@7edf86d3
18/06/03 17:35:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, executor driver): UnknownReason
18/06/03 17:35:14 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
18/06/03 17:35:14 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.None$
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1866)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1749)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2040)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2285)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2209)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2067)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1571)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:313)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/06/03 17:35:14 INFO Executor: Executor is trying to kill task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2), reason: Stage cancelled
18/06/03 17:35:14 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Stage 0 was cancelled
18/06/03 17:35:14 ERROR TaskResultGetter: Could not deserialize TaskEndReason: ClassNotFound with classloader sbt.classpath.ClasspathFilter@7edf86d3
18/06/03 17:35:14 INFO DAGScheduler: **ResultStage 0 (count at HelloWorldExample.scala:25) failed in 0.363 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): UnknownReason
Driver stacktrace:**
18/06/03 17:35:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): UnknownReason
18/06/03 17:35:14 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
18/06/03 17:35:14 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: count at HelloWorldExample.scala:25, took 0.438299 s
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): UnknownReason
[error] Driver stacktrace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): UnknownReason
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2067)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2092)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1162)
        at org.koeninger.HelloWorldExample$.main(HelloWorldExample.scala:25)
        at org.koeninger.HelloWorldExample.main(HelloWorldExample.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
18/06/03 17:35:20 INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
18/06/03 17:35:21 INFO AsyncEventQueue: Stopping listener queue executorManagement.
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:94)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1319)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:78)
18/06/03 17:35:21 INFO AsyncEventQueue: Stopping listener queue appStatus.
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch$1.apply(AsyncEventQueue.scala:94)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue.org$apache$spark$scheduler$AsyncEventQueue$$dispatch(AsyncEventQueue.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsyncEventQueue.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1319)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.AsyncEventQueue$$anon$1.run(AsyncEventQueue.scala:78)
18/06/03 17:35:21 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1319)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:178)
        at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:73)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

- Version Details:

  spark version - 2.1.2

  cassandra version - 2.2.12

  spark-cassandra-connector version - 2.3.0-s_2.11

  scala version - 2.11

Could you please advise?

Build.scala:

```
import sbt._

import Keys._

import sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin.autoImport._


object CassandraExampleBuild extends Build {
  lazy val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
    version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    organization := "org.koeninger",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.2"
  )

  lazy val app = Project(

    "cassandra-example",

   file("."),

   settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(

      parallelExecution in Test := false,

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

       "datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.3.0-s_2.11" ,

      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % "1.3.0",

      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.0",

    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test"
 )
 )
 )
}
```

Code Block:

```
 val hello = sc.cassandraTable[String]("tutorial", "user")

println(hello.count)
```

Comment: There's probably not enough information here to answer the question. Can you produce a [mcve]?

Comment: looks like scala version mismatch issue so make sure you are using compatible scala version for each of the applications

Comment: What's in the `build.sbt`? Are you sure that you have all dependencies for scala version 2.11, not 2.10 or 2.12?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have added all the dependencies compatible with scala 2.11. please find the attached build.scala file.

Comment: This code block is running successfully through scala shell, but giving me error when trying to run through sbt.
Please suggest anything.

Comment: issue is resolved:
used the following set of versions for compatibility-
versions
spark - 2.3.0
spark-cassandra - 2.3.0
sbt  - 0.13.17
sbt assembly - 0.14.6
cassandra - 2.2.12
scala - 2.11.8